# When do MySQL DBA need root access

Tags: mysql

For a MySQL DBA, what operations require root access. I know that we need to be root for installation, starting and stopping services. With DBA’s not having root access, is there a way to perform majority of the operations?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the mysqld is started as mysql user (in the init script is something like *su mysql*). Therefore there is no other option beside having access to this user.

But you can setup your system to [run mysqld as a normal user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/changing-mysql-user.html).